# How to split string vector by first desired symbol in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example.

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(x=c("a-b-c", "b-d","c-d_e-f"))
df
#        x
#1   a-b-c
#2     b-d
#3 c-d_e-f
```

What I wanted is to `separate` the column `x` by the first `-`, thus a desired output would be:

```
  x     y
1 a   b-c
2 b     d
3 c d_e-f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    extract(x, into = c('x', 'y'), '^([^-])+-(.*)')
```

---

Or with `separate` with making use of `extra`

```
df %>%
    separate(x, into = c('x', 'y'), '-', extra = 'merge')
#   x     y
#1 a   b-c
#2 b     d
#3 c d_e-f
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) separate** Use `separate` in the tidyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(x, c("x", "y"), sep = "-", extra = "merge")
```

giving:

```
  x     y
1 a   b-c
2 b     d
3 c d_e-f
```

**2) Base R**  Without using any packages we can use `read.table`.  Replace the first minus with space first.

```
read.table(text = sub("-", " ", df$x), col.names = c("x", "y"), as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  x     y
1 a   b-c
2 b     d
3 c d_e-f
```

**3) read.fwf** If the first field is always one character, as it is in the question, then we can use `read.fwf`

```
read.fwf(file = textConnection(as.character(df$x)), widths = c(1, 1, 99), 
  colClasses = c(NA, "NULL", NA), col.names = c("x", NA, "y"))
```

giving:

```
  x     y
1 a   b-c
2 b     d
3 c d_e-f
```

Comment: Awesome. That's what I am looking. Thanks +1